Connecting to External WebSockets Vertx Core (3.9.12) Java
I've been trying to setup a WebSocket client in Java with the Vertx Core 3.9.12's HTTP Client and I can't seem to figure out how to use it to connect to non-localhost servers. All the examples I've seen of using Vertx WebSocket clients have been with localhost and I can't seem to figure out the exact way to configure the client to hit an example WS page like wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw or echo.websocket.org/.ws.
I've tried a modified and updated version of the Vertx Ping Pong https://alexey-soshin.medium.com/playing-ping-pong-over-websockets-with-vert-x-447c634c6c87. However, I have been unable to translate this into contacting a non-localhost endpoint.
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

//        vertx.deployVerticle(new WebSocksServerVerticle(), (__) -> {
            vertx.deployVerticle(new WebSocksClientVerticle());
//        });
    }

    static class WebSocksServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
        @Override
        public void start() {
            startServer(vertx);
        }

        private void startServer(Vertx vertx) {
//            HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions();
//            options.setHost("172.28.87.34");


            HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

            server.websocketHandler((ctx) -> {
                ctx.writeTextMessage("ping");

                ctx.textMessageHandler((msg) -> {
                    System.out.println("Server " + msg);

                    if ((new Random()).nextInt(100) == 0) {
                        ctx.close();
                    } else {
                        ctx.writeTextMessage("ping");
                    }
                });
            }).listen(8080);
        }
    }

    static class WebSocksClientVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
        @Override
        public void start() {
            startClient(vertx);
        }

        private void startClient(Vertx vertx) {
//            HttpClientOptions
            HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();

            client.webSocket("ws.postman-echo.com", "/raw", (asyncResult) -> {
                System.out.println(asyncResult.succeeded());
                if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    WebSocket socket = asyncResult.result();
                    System.out.println(socket);
                    socket.textMessageHandler((msg) -> {
                        System.out.println("Client " + msg);
                        socket.writeTextMessage("ping");
                    }).exceptionHandler((e) -> {
                        System.out.println("Closed, restarting in 10 seconds");
                        restart(client, 5);
                    }).closeHandler((__) -> {
                        System.out.println("Closed, restarting in 10 seconds");
                        restart(client, 10);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        private void restart(HttpClient client, int delay) {
            client.close();
            vertx.setTimer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(delay), (__) -> {
                startClient(vertx);
            });
        }
    }
}

